# Naming php files: what do 'class.php' and 'html.php' extension mean?

Tags: php

Just curious, I've noticed that some php files have extension 'class.php' or 'html.php'. What is the reason for a code file to have such extensions?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a custom thing, maybe class.php extensions are "models" and html.php files are "views"

Answer (score 1):

Depends on creation, it might mean like:

- "class.php" => refers to class files like somethis.class.php
- ".html.php" => refers to some templates like something.html.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, class.php are models/handlers and html.php are views

Comment: you really should mention that this is just a custom way of doing things - nothing really stops me from writing a template/view in a `something.class.php`.

Answer (score 0):

It has no specific meaning. Most likely `.class.php` contains a classe and `.html.php` could be a template.

Using `ClassName.class.php` has the advantage that you can safely use autoloading to include `$className.'.class.php'` in the `__autoload()` function without possible conflicts (e.g. with a class named `index` - you most likely have an `index.php` but that class' file would be `index.class.php` so it would not be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Having files with .php are executed by the PHP engine. Some people like to use periods as extensions of their uses.

ie
`create.my.template.html.php`

`create.my.template.html` is the file name. `.php` is the extension.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't have any special effect, as the real extension is still just *.php*. one might choose to name files like this to seperate views and models or something like that - but you could also use subfolders (named *html* and *class* for example) or don't use any kind of naming convention at all (wich might end up in a very confusing file-structure.)